# Text between spaces on flutter

Tags: flutter

Currently I have a code for product price, name, and old price, and when I code it, it gives me this very unsatisfying style:

[image]

How do I code in such a way that I get the product name on top, price in the middle and the old price on the very bottom vertically? For example:

**Chicken Lunchbox**

**Old Price: 55,000**

**New Price: 45,000**

In this format? I would appreciate the assistance.

Here is my code responsible for this image:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
          tag: prod_name,
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: GridTile(
                  footer: Container(
                    color: Colors.white70,
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Text(
                        prod_name,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12.0, ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                          "\$$prod_price",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,fontSize: 12.0,),
                      ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "\$$prod_old_price",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          decoration
                              :TextDecoration.lineThrough),
                      ),
                    )
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                    prod_picture,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use column in subtitle to achieve desire ui more easily.

Try Following code:

```
ListTile(
          title: Text("Checken LunchBox"),
          subtitle: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text("Oldprice :55,000"),
              Text("NewPrice :55,000"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Column` widget. It's a widget that displays its children in a vertical array.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text('title'),
    Text('price'),
    Text('prev_price'),
  ],
)
```

For more info checkout: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html